# Impala's RPM bounce

Tags: engine, chevrolet, rpm

I have a 2003 Chevy impala LS 3800 motor ... anyways, the RPM's tack will bounce while in overdrive and seems to be random at every time; It could be weeks on end but then it could do so everyday. It only happens while in overdrive and tends to stop when shifting into 3rd gear. I have replaced pretty much the entire car; oil pressure sensor, radiator, cooling fan, MAFS (mass air flow sensor), steering pump, plastic elbows alternator, and fuel filter (if that helps). The car was $700 and in bad shape not really road safe until i got parts. So i'm not really to sure what all has been done to the motor itself since before I owned it.

Another note: why does my car start, struggle to stay started then die after being ran for a bit? Like if i go to Walmart and shut off the car, I have to wait half hour to 45 minutes later for the engine to cool. The dash and fluids are fine but its like it struggles to stay "alive" after being ran. I've gotten into a habbit of just leaving my car on if i have to run into a gas station or something in fear of it not restarting ... could that be a crank related issue? I'm not really car smart but i can tell you if something isn't right.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many miles are on the Impala? The first "problem" sounds like it could be the lock up in the torque converter not working correctly. The second would most likely not be the crank at issue. Don't know what it is, though it sounds as though something is getting heat soaked and not wanting to play after the engine has been shut down.

Comment: It has 245k on the motor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The torque convertor clutch is powered by one of several solenoids inside the transmission drain pan. The grounding wire screws can loosen.
On problem 2, the ignition module could be faulty as it heats up during a hot soak. If you can borrow a timing light, use it to check for spark when it gets hard to start.